QML attribute binding failed
I tried to bind the value of a slider bar to a property value of a ListElement, but when the property of the ListElement changed, the value of the slider bar did not change accordingly, which means that the binding was not successful
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
ApplicationWindow{
    width: 1000
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel{
        id: deviceModel
        ListElement{value:100}
        ListElement{value:100}
        ListElement{value:100}
        ListElement{value:100}
    }

    property var temp: deviceModel.get(0);

    Slider{
        id:slider
        from:0
        to:10000
        value: temp.value //Bind the value of the slider bar to the value attribute of the global object temp
    }

    Timer{
        interval: 1000
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered:{
            temp.value+=100
            console.log(temp.value)
            console.log(slider.value)
            /* Output result: It can be found that the value of Slider does not change with the change of the temp's value atrribute
            qml: 1500
            qml: 500
            qml: 2500
            qml: 500
            qml: 3500
            qml: 500
            qml: 4500
            qml: 500
              */
        }
    }
} 


Because you're using deviceModel.get(0) you're having a one-way access to your ListModel. To put values back you should consider using deviceModel.put(...).
However, QML already has built-in two-way access to your model. You should consider using ListView (or Repeater). Then when you need to post values write them directly to the ListModel.
    ListModel{
        id: deviceModel
        ListElement{deviceValue:100}
        ListElement{deviceValue:100}
        ListElement{deviceValue:100}
        ListElement{deviceValue:100}
    }
    
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: deviceModel
        delegate: Column {
            Slider{
                id:slider
                from:0
                to:10000
                value: deviceValue
                onValueChanged: deviceValue = value
            }
            
            Timer{
                interval: 1000
                running: true
                repeat: true
                onTriggered:{
                    deviceValue+=100
                    console.log(deviceValue)
                }
            }
        }
    }

You can Try it Online!
If you want to show only one element in your ListModel consider using DelegateModel.
